# mongodb append to an existing object

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, mongodb-query

here is my document, and I want to add a new field to it:

```
{ 
email_address: 'webmaster@example.com', 
password: 'random_password',
first_name: 'John',
last_name: 'Doe',
website: {
    main_title: 'My Blog Website',
    main_url: 'http://www.example.com'
    }
}
```

currently i am doing:

```
db.test.update({"email_address": "webmaster@example.com"},
{$set: {"website" : {"registrar": "namecheap"}}})
```

this erases the other fields inside *website* and just adds this new *registrar* field. how can I append to it?

Comment: I think  $push is what you are looking for

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use [dot-notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to set value to particular field of the sub-document, instead of setting the whole sub-document:

```
db.test.update(
    { "email_address": "webmaster@example.com" },
    { $set: { "website.registrar" : "namecheap" } }
)
```